# Find a, b and c that makes a cumulative distribution function: What limits to evaluate?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x < 0 \\
\dfrac{x^2}a, & 0 \le x < 1 \\
\dfrac{x - 1}b, & 1\le x < 2 \\
c\dfrac{6x - x^2 - 1}2, & 2\le x \le 3 \\
1, & x > 3
\end{cases}$$

So:

- to find $a$, I need to evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^2}a$ and solve for $a$
- to find $b$, I need to evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{x - 1}b$ and solve for $b$
- to find $c$, I need to evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to3}c\dfrac{6x - x^2 - 1}2$ and solve for $c$

Is this right? 
Why $2$ is not evaluated on looking for $c$?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "limF(x)-> **0** in (x^2)/a". Do you mean $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^2}a$? Same for the remaining cases.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And 2<= x <3 its actually 2<= x <=3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no probability associated with $1,2,$ or $3$ the cdf must be continuous.  The only threats are at $1,2,3$ where you change from one form to another.  $x=0$ does not provide any information except $a \neq 0$.  If you evaluate the limits on each side of $1,2,3$ you get
$$\frac{1^2}a=\frac {1-1}b\\
\frac {2-1}b=c\frac{6\cdot 2-2^2-1}2\\
c\frac{6\cdot 3-3^2-1}2=1$$
You would solve these three to get $a,b,c$.  The problem is flawed because the first cannot be satisfied.  You would start with the third to get $c$, then plug that value for $c$ into the second and get $b$, then (assuming the numerator on the right of the first were not $0$) plug that into the first and get $a$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $X$ is $\underline{\textrm{continuous}}$ distributed and not mixed distributed. I probably identified a typo/mistake-the red 2. If it is right the cdf is

$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \le 0 \\ \frac{x^2}{a}, & 0 < x \le 1 \\ \frac{\color{red}2x-1}{b}, & 1 < x \le 2 \\ c\cdot \frac{6x-x^2-1}{2}, & 2 < x \le 3 \\ 1, & 3 < x. \end{cases}$$

Then following equations must hold:

- $\frac1a=\frac{2\cdot 1-1}{b}$
- $\frac{2\cdot 2-1}{b}=c\cdot \frac{6\cdot 2-2^2-1}{2}$
- $c\cdot \frac{6\cdot 3-3^2-1}{2}=1$

Comment: Why should the red number be $2$ as opposed to any other number except $1$?

Comment: @RossMillikan I´ve chosen that number since the function is very similar to the sum of two uniformly distributed variables $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $Y\sim(0,2)$